# predict_and_parse warning in Multi-Route chains in langchain

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, langchain-js

I have been working on Multi-Route Chains in Langchain. I am getting the output but along with the output I am also getting the predict_and_parse deprecation warning. How do I get rid of this warning?

I am attaching the screenshot of the warning FYR

[predict_and_parse deprecation warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X756x.png)

I tried changing the output parser in the PromptTemplate.

`router_prompt = PromptTemplate(template=router_temp,input_variables=['input'], output_parser=RouterOutputParser())`

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```